# Int cannot be derefrenced

Tags: java

I am trying to learn how to program in Java. Right now I am writing a code, but I am getting an error that I have looked all over for, but cant seem to find the answer. The objective is to have the user enter 8 numbers and then to get the computer to output the highest number and the lowest number.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class StevensMarissaHighestLowestPoints
    {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    System.out.print("Enter the the score of the Texans first 8 games: ");

    System.out.println("\nGame One Score: ");
    int game1 = game1.nextInt();

    System.out.println("\nGame Two Score: ");
    int game2 = game2.nextInt();

    System.out.println("\nGame Three Score: ");
    int game3 = game3.nextInt();

    System.out.println("\nGame Four Score: ");
    int game4 = game4.nextInt();

    System.out.println("\nGame Five Score: ");
    int game5 = game5.nextInt();

    System.out.println("\nGame Six Score: ");
    int game6 = game6.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Game Seven Score: ");
    int game7 = game7.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Game Eight Score: ");
    int game8 = game8.nextInt();

    System.out.println("The highest score of the season is: " + 
    Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    System.out.println("The lowest score of the season in: " + 
    Integer.MAX_VALUE);



    }
}
```

Comment: `int game1 = game1.nextInt();` You should be calling `nextInt` on your `Scanner` object.

Comment: i.e. `int game1 = sc.nextInt();` and so on. You might also consider using a loop to remove the repetition in the code.

Comment: Yeah i realized that.. Dumb mistake.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must run `nextInt` on `sc`, your Scanner object. It's trying to deref an object but primitives (in this case `int`s) arent objects.

Also, this won't achieve your goals if you are trying to figure out which `game` has the largest value; you would need to run something like a recursive Math.min and max call or with all your numbers, ex:

```
Math.min(a, Math.min(b, c))
```

Comment: Okay so i tried the Math.min(a, Math.min(b,c)) but what do i do for the other numbers, I tried Math.min(a, Math.min(b,c, Math.min(d,e))) and i cant seem to get it to futher past just the first three numbers

Comment: @MarissaStevens Math.min takes two arguments